# Python Mock: How to inject an object at a specific point in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Given multiple calls to an object (say subprocess calls) in a function, is it possible to mock a specific subprocess call? The goal would be to pinpoint a specific logic case to manipulate for unit testing. Or is this just a limitation of mocking (or SDET abilities), and I need to break up the bigger function into smaller ones so that they only contain one subprocess call and each one can be mocked and unit tested individually?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's possible, but you can make the mock do whatever the original method would have done.

```
import mock, sys


def bar(n):
    print('bar({})'.format(n))


def foo():
    bar(1)
    bar(2)
    bar(3)


class MockBar(mock.MagicMock):

    original = staticmethod(bar)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.call_count == 1:
            print('stubbed a call with args {} and kwargs {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        else:
            MockBar.original(*args, **kwargs)
        super(MockBar, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


with mock.patch.object(sys.modules[__name__], 'bar', MockBar()):
    foo()
```

As an example I have mocked out only the second call to `bar`, out of three calls total.  So running this code above gives the output:

```
bar(1)
stubbed a call with args (2,) and kwargs {}
bar(3)
```